# IIS 8.5 throws HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: iis-8

Trying to call one wep application from another web application where send the data via request xml as POST request.  Facing  **HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large** for the large request xml. Using boncode as connector and IIS 8.5

Comment: The error message sounds fairly self-explanatory. What's your question exactly?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default file upload size is 49 KB (49152 bytes).

**Solution:**

The quickest solution is to increase the upload size limit. IIS uses uploadReadAheadSize parameter in applicationHost.config and web.config files to control this limit.

Steps to change the value of this parameter:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Select the site
3. Double click "Configuration Editor"
4. Select system.webServer and then serverRuntime
5. Modify the uploadReadAheadSize value
6. Click "Apply"

[image]

You may also want to change maxRequestEntityAllowed parameter. It specifies the maximum number of bytes allowed in the request body.